# Java - Why am I getting this NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I don't understand why this is giving me a null pointer exception when I try to add a value to the a1[i] array.

```
public class Array {

String text;
int total = 0, count = 0;

Array[] a1 = new Array[100];
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);



public void setData() {
    int i=0;

    System.out.println(a1.length);
    do {

        System.out.println("Enter some data: ");
        text = scan.next();
        if (text.equals("end"))break;
        a1[i].text = text; //I get a null pointer exception here. Not sure why. 
        i++;

    } while (true);

    }
```

Comment: Why are you using an array of type Array, surely you meant to use some other object instead? e.g String[] a1 = new String[100]

Comment: You're getting a null pointer because a1[i] is null. Declaring an array of objects does not mean they're initialised to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything initialized in the `a1` array is `null`.  You'd have to put a new instance of `Array()` in there before doing anything with the member methods.

What this translates to:  Every time you want to do something with `a1[i]`, you'd have to have a new instance of `Array` in there first.

Example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    a1[i] = new Array();
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help.  Be sure to accept the answer that helped you out the most.

Answer (score 0):

Because there isn't an object stored at a1[i].  What you're essentially saying at that line is:

```
null.text = text
```

which will break every time

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a null-pointer exception, because you have allocated the space for 100 array elements, but you still need to initialize them:

So before accessing `a1[i].text` you need to initialize it by calling `a1[i] = new Array()`

Also I am quite sure, that you actually wanted to create some other kind of object, not `Array`. Array the class you are currently writing, as I understand, so you probably want to have multiple `String`s, e.g. String[].

I recommend to you to use a LinkedList instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array[] a1 = new Array[100]; //here you just create an array of references to objects which are set to null
a1[i].text = text; //before this line you should assign to a1[i] a reference to Array object for example a1[i] = new Array();
```