# Why am I getting a NullPointerException with my array?

Tags: java, interface, nullpointerexception

I cant figure out why I am getting a NullPointerException. What am I missing here ?

```
public class CustomJourneyUserInformation {
    public IJourneyDetails journeyDetails;
    public IUserDetails userDetails;
    public ISubscribeJourney subscribedToJourneys;
}
```

IJourneyDetails, IUserDetails, ISubscribeJourney are all interfaces

In a different activity, I am calling

```
private CustomJourneyUserInformation[] allJourneyDetails;
    allJourneyDetails = new CustomJourneyUserInformation[subscribedToJourneys.length];
    if (providerDetails[i] != null)
>>> allJourneyDetails[i].journeyDetails = providerDetails[i];
    if (userDetails[i] != null)
    allJourneyDetails[i].userDetails = userDetails[i];
    if (subscribedToJourneys[i] != null)
        allJourneyDetails[i].subscribedToJourneys = subscribedToJourneys[i];
```

I am getting a null pointer exception in line marked by >>>>

I am sure `allJourneyDetails[i]` is null here.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, was thinking of making the change anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Why am I getting this NullPointerException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968336/java-why-am-i-getting-this-nullpointerexception)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like `allJourneyDetails[i]` is null, since the array is still filled with `null` after initialization.

Did you expect creating the array to fill the array with non-null values?  That's not how it works in Java.

Comment: Surprisingly, I have seen the same problem being faced by beginners so many times.

Comment: IIRC, new arrays in C++ are already initialized with entries, which might be why so many beginners are surprised.

Comment: Hmm. So, it seems, transition is the culprit ;)

Comment: God knows I am not a beginner.. :). Fixed it with adding  `allJourneyDetails[i] = new CustomJourneyUserInformation();` inside the for loop. Silly array initialization goof up. Use so much of ArrayLists that goofed up on []'s.

Answer (score 2):

```
allJourneyDetails = new CustomJourneyUserInformation[subscribedToJourneys.length];
```

should be

```
allJourneyDetails = new CustomJourneyUserInformation[providerDetails.length];
```

too; but @LouisWasserman is right